# Reactivate code after filter is used

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

I am not very known with jQuery in combination with jQuery Migrate. The site I am working on uses jQuery 1.12 with Migrate version 1.4.1

After some searching the below script works fine at page load:

```
jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).data('href');
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    return false;
});
```

But after some filter build the old fashioned way, this listener is 'forgotten'.

What to do?

Comment: If the `.single_add_to_cart_button` element is removed and then recreated in the DOM then you'll need to use a delegated event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the element, where the listener is attached to. This happens probably at the filtering time. You can circumvent that behavior, if you set the listener on a parent element, which is not being removed at all (e.g. in a `<td>` the `<table>` element). I would not set the listener at the top level (`document`), because it is much more performing to set it on a parent, which is not being removed. If you set the listener to the `document`, every click is being watched and searched for the `.single_add_to_cart_button` element.

You can set the listener to the parent, but only reacting to clicks on `.single_add_to_cart_button` if you use the following snippet:

```
jQuery("#tableWithId").on("click", ".single_add_to_cart_button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).data('href');
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Jeez. At first jQuery(document) did not work. Thanx anyways

Answer (score 1):

If the elements that match `.single_add_to_cart_button` are removed and re-added, you need to use delegation aka place the listener on an element that's always there (body, document) and then only run it on elements that match your given query, as such:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.single_add_to_cart_button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = jQuery(this).data('href');
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    return false;
});
```